# How to restore GnuPG key after reinstall?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

I know that GnuPG is all about security, thus it's not giving many chance of retrieve private keys (otherwise anyone could do it) but I've got a private key, and my own rev.asc file.

I had to reinstall my Ubuntu box (former Ubuntu Studio) and I have backup of /home and /etc.

Is it possible to recover my GnuPG key instead of revoke it and create another one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, GPG stores everything under the `.gnupg` directory in your home directory. (Your encrypted private key should be in `~/.gnupg/secring.gpg`).

Restoring the entire `~/.gnupg` directory from your backup will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, something must have gone wrong, because I cannot find my ~/.gnupg directory in the backup...probably I lost it before (or during) the disaster that lead me to the reinstall.

Comment: @dag729: just in case you don't know this - `ls` will consider files and folders starting with a dot to be invisible. Use `ls -a` to show everything in the backup of your home directory.